Getting error on solana-test-sol
Hi tell me how can I get the test sol?
I already request, but empty now message occur.
what am I gonna do?

Do you mean devnet sol?
Here is a guide with 6 ways on how to get devnet sol:
https://solana.com/de/developers/guides/getstarted/solana-token-airdrop-and-faucets
including a web faucet and discord bots.
